# javascript cookies for variable

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to create something like wallet.

```
function putMoney(){

    myMoney = [];
    var inputMoney = document.getElementById("input").value;
    mon = "";
    for(i = 0; i< myMoney.length; i++){
        mon = mon + myMoney[i];
    }

    var a = document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.getElementById("showmoney").innerHTML = a;

};
```

my question is: How to save the value in the textbox?

Comment: How about assigning your value to `value` property of the textbox?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If the id of the textbox is "txtVal",

document.getElementById("txtVal").value = value;

or with Jquery,

$("#txtVal").val(value);